# Dividing a time-format column into specified number of discrete intervals in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, discrete

I have a column names `ViolationTime` in my Hive table. It contains time in 24-hour `HHmm` format, for example 1424.
The table contains 10 million rows. I want to divide it into 6 discrete groups to perform operations.

I tried using `ntile`, but it will divide the values based on ascending or descending order. I'd like this column to be divided in discrete intervals.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried using `WHERE...BETWEEN`6 times for each group?

Answer (score 0):

In Hive 3.0 and newer, the [`width_bucket()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-MathematicalFunctions) function does that:

> Return type: INT
>  Name (signature):    width_bucket(NUMERIC expr,
> NUMERIC min_value, NUMERIC max_value, INT num_buckets)
> Description:  Returns an integer between 0 and num_buckets+1 by mapping
> expr into the ith equally sized bucket. Buckets are made by dividing
> [min_value, max_value] into equally sized regions. If expr <
> min_value, return 1, if expr > max_value return num_buckets+1.

Although you may find that you need to convert your `HHmm` time values to INTs first (e.g. number of seconds since midnight), to make it work perfectly well.